# Share project files between Visual Studio .net and Eclipse java

Tags: java, .net, visual-studio, maven, nuget

We currently have 3 teams working with same set of .json files : java .net and python.

The files are static data which changes not very often. They need to be deployed with executables. So they are code-agnostic assets

They are part of .net solution and java project (not sure how python guys structure theirs)

If there are changes in the files .net and python are going to java github repo and download them, replace locally, check in into their repos. There are also 2 different .net teams using it in separate VS solutions and separate github repos.

Is there a way to automate it? Or better share from the single source?

We use enterprise github

Comment: Can you include the data repo as a Git submodule? They'd be in their own repo, but easily included in all other Git repos.

Comment: I don't know. I never heard of submodules. Tell me more please

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @BoppityBop Hi, any update of this question? :)

Comment: Jorn idea it sounds good.. but java team rejected the approach. so i couldnt test..